# absolute mouse buttons on dock

Tags: macos, mouse

I have created an absolute mouse piece of hardware.

This is very much like a wacom tablet, but it just uses a regular mouse going into a piece of hardware that then increments or decrements the X and Y coordinates in order to specify the exact location of the mouse (yes I need to do this for another reason).

While everything works fine on multiple operating systems, it works fine on Mac OSX Yosemite except ---->

When I move to the dock, if I click on an icon it will not start the application, I can move the icon and once open I can close the app or scroll, anything you would expect from a mouse, it will not start properly.  Also the back arrow in the system settings/preferences will only operate if I am on the exact right location on the button, i.e. normally there is no back action, but if I mess with it and get it in just the right location it will finally work.

This sounds like an oversight in the operating system, does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: insight into what? we fix code, we don't read through vague rambling descriptions of problems and try to **GUESS** what the problem might be. since you've provided nothing actually useful (e.g. code), here's the only answer we can give you: have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Apologies for my manner in asking this question.  Ultimately I am looking for insight into the MAC OS and how I might fix it's faulty handling of an absolute position mouse; the rest of my write up was to explain what I meant by absolute position mouse and why I need this since I did not want to get into the conversation about just witching back to a relative mouse.